# Return array reference from hash keys or returning sub routine

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to find a way where I can return the array reference of all the keys of a hash.

for example

```
sub example {
    my %hash = (
        'one' => [1,11,111],
        'two' => [2,22,222],
        'three' => [3,33,333]
         .
         .
        'nine' => [9,99,999]
    );

 return sort keys %hash;
}
```

Now if I get all the keys of the hash, I will get an array containing one, two .. nine. I am asking how can i return the array reference here ?

Do i have to do something like this ?

```
my @array = sort keys %hash;
return \@array;
```

Is there a better way to do it ? Something like `return \@{sort keys %hash}` ?

If that is not possible, then how can I create a reference of a sub routine which is returning me array ?

In my example, if i have go by original `return sort keys %hash`, and then I want to pass this array as reference to some other sub routine, how can I do it ?

Example:

```
sub other_routine {
    my $array_ref = shift;

    ## do something with $array_ref;
}

other_routine (\example());
```

Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

P.S. - Unfortunately, I have to run this script on a very old server which has perl 5.8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous arrays and hashes existed in 5.8.3, too. You even use them in the code.

```
return [ keys %hash ]
```

If a subroutine returns a list, you can't make it into a reference by adding a `\`: it would be distributed, i.e. you'll get an array of references to the members of the list. You can still use an anonymous array, though:

```
my $ref = [ sub_that_returns_list() ];
```